# Within an extension how can load a custom `Civi` name-spaced class?

Tags: developer

Within my extension I can load classes from CiviCRM's core codebase like this:

```
$foo = new \Civi\Core\AssetBuilder();
```

And I can also load custom classes that I've written in my extension like this:

```
$foo = new CRM_MyExtension_MyClass();
```

Cool.

---

But if I've defined a custom class within my extension using the `Civi` namespace, the following does not work:

```
$foo = new \Civi\MyExtension\MyClass();
```

It fails with this error message:

> Error: Class 'Civi\MyExtension\MyClass' not found in ...

How can I load this custom class from within my extension?

Answer (score 7):

Add the following elements to your extension's `info.xml` file to enable [PSR-4 autoloading](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/):

```
<classloader>
  <psr4 prefix="Civi\" path="Civi"/>
</classloader>
```

Also see docs on the [`<classloader>` element](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/info-xml/#classloader)